# Visual Editor for eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-editor

I made a class that represents a composite.  I want this composite to take up all available space.  How can I do this and have it show up full size in the designer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should choose in your parent composite for example FillLayout.

Another way is to choose GridLayout and then set up GridData in your composite to expand on all parent composite.

You can read more about layouts in SWT here:

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html